# How to send captured image to the Apache Server?

Tags: android, performance, image-processing

I have written the code for capturing the image from the camera and send to the server. But sometimes it works sometimes its not with the error volley timeout error. And almost all the cases when I am using JIO network which used IPv6 IP( I don't know what is affecting this) its not working.

I am capturing the image and convert into base64 and sending to the POST to the PHP server.

To start the camera :

```
  btn_cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                captureImage();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

After capturing the image :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Then sending the encoded string to the APACHE server :

```
       btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            _house_no = house_number.getText().toString();
            _state = state.getText().toString();
            _streetName = locality.getText().toString();
            _city = city.getText().toString();
            _postalCode = postcode.getText().toString();
            _state = state.getText().toString();
            _district = district.getText().toString();
            _tahsil = "0";

            final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Please wait...", false, false);


            try {
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                String URL = ServerLinks.SUBMIT;
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();

                jObj.put("userID",userID);
                jObj.put("house",_house_no);
                jObj.put("street",_streetName);
                jObj.put("city",_city);
                jObj.put("post_code",_postalCode);
                jObj.put("state",_state);
                jObj.put("district",_district);
                jObj.put("lat",lat);
                jObj.put("long",longi);
                jObj.put("image",encoded);
                final String requestBody = jObj.toString();
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("FINAL_SUBMIT_RESPONSE", response.toString());
                        loading.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                            int response_code = object.getInt("code");
                            String message = object.getString("Message");
                            if (response_code == 400) {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                house_number.setText("");
                            } else {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        loading.dismiss();
                        VolleyLog.d("RESULT_ERROR", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something Went Wrong!! Please submit it again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {


                    @Override
                    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                        try {
                            return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                            VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        params.put("x-api-key", OAuth);
                        return params;
                    }

                };
                stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
                requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}`
```

Can you please help me how should I increase the efficiency of my form with the image. Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

Inside my code I have done this like that :

```
 HttpClient httpclient;
    httpclient = HttpClientSingalTon.getHttpClienttest();
    HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);
    // Try This
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
    MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    ContentBody cbFile = new FileBody(yourimagefile, "image/jpeg");
    mpEntity.addPart("file", cbFile); 
    httpPostRequest.setEntity(mpEntity);
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
```

Comment: What's the difference I used Volley and you have used HttpClient

Comment: @PiyushSahay this multipart approach is best rather then base64 string.